# Display the files in the Application's Documents folder in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, document

I saw this feature in a Downloader app that I found and I would like to use that feature in my app that I am making.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Apple documentation for NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000305-2894) and it will tell you how to get the directory contents into an array. Specifically you are looking for `directorycontentsatpath`.

Once you have the Array, then just populate the UITableview with the contents of the array.